# Basic doubt in Vector please explain

Tags: vectors

[image]

> If the resultant of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ is $\perp$ (perpendicular) to $\vec{A}$, then it means that
>
> - $B\sin\theta = |\vec{A}|$
> - $R = B\cos\theta$
>
> So angle b|w (between) $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B} = 90^\circ + 60^\circ = 150^\circ$ given that $R = B/2 \implies B/2 = B\cos\theta \implies \cos\theta = 1/2 \implies \theta = 60^\circ$

How is $B\sin\theta$ equal to the magnitude of $\vec{A}$ and $B\cos\theta = R$?

$B\cos\theta$ can be big or smaller than $R$, so how can we say that they have same value?

Please  explain.

Answer (score 1):

This is not stated explicitly, but $\vec R$ must be defined as

$\vec R = \vec A + \vec B$

Since we know that $\vec R$ is perpendicular to $\vec A$, then $|\vec A|$ and $|\vec R|$ are perpendicular components of the vector $\vec B$. Since the angle between $\vec B$ and $\vec R$ is $\theta$, we have

$|\vec R| = |\vec B| \cos \theta$

and

$|\vec A| = |\vec B| \sin \theta$

Comment: Actually, it is stated with statement "_If the resultant of $\vec A$ 
 and $\vec B$ is [...]_". If it's vector algebra course, then it's natural to assume that word **AND** in this context means vector addition. By given schematics it can only be a vector $R$, due to clearly seen [parallelogram law](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelogramLaw.html) in the picture.